# No output when trying to make a countdown timer in c

Tags: c, sleep, countdown, carriage-return

I'm trying to make a rudimentary countdown timer with the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Enter time in minutes:");
    int x = 0;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    x = x*60;
    while(x!=0) {
        printf("Remaining time is %d\r", x);
        x--;
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I run the code for x = 1, I get no immediate output. Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard output is line buffered by default. If it's

```
printf("Remaining time is %d\n", x);
```

Note the `\n` here, it would output every time a `\n` is seen.

However, in your case, you use the carriage return `\r` on purpose. The alternative method is to flush the standard out manually like this:

```
printf("Remaining time is %d\r", x);
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Could you explain what I was missing?

Comment: @waivek Added a little explanation.

Comment: `Printf` doesn't flush it's output by default, that is, it writes to an internal buffer, and when full or at line-end, that buffer is printed to the screen.  Your problem is that you were not filling that buffer or outputting `'\n'`, and so output was not pushed to the screen. `fflush(stdout)` forces the buffer to be written each time. edit: too slow...